# Jenkins - get last Unstable build status

Tags: api, jenkins

```
http://$host/job/$jobname/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json
```

Above URL is helping me to get last completed build status.

This [Document](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Terminology)
tells the defination of **Unstable build**. - A build is unstable if it was built successfully and one or more publishers report it unstable. For example if the JUnit publisher is configured and a test fails then the build will be marked unstable.

How can I get Unstable build details through api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the api-documentation is looks like this: 
http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Job.html#getLastUnstableBuild()

If you just check http://$host/job/$jobname/api/json you should see the same corresponding parts in the xml.

```
http://$host/job/$jobname/lastUnstableBuild/api/json
```

Comment: Do that job have any unstable builds? The one I tried first didn't have one and gave me 404 too.

Comment: ohhh ok.. let me check in build having unstable job.

Comment: yes.. it worked for builds having unstable job. Thanks @MaTePe